# How can I use the Brier Skill Score in cross-validation for imbalanced data?

Tags: python, class-imbalance, hyperparameter-tuning

I wish to use search for model hyper-parameters (by a grid search) using the [Brier score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score) as the scoring method (see code below):

```
 kfolds = StratifiedKFold(3)
 clf = GridSearchCV(model, parameters, cv=kfolds.split(x, y),
                           scoring='neg_brier_score', return_train_score=True, n_jobs=n_jobs)
```

The problem is, I have a class-imbalance problem, and I couldn't find an implementation of the Brier score that works with this. 
 Is there a version of the Brier score that is appropriate problems? And if not, why?

Comment: The Brier score, as opposed to log-loss (binary cross-entropy), doesn't really differentiate between low probabilities (e.g. 0.01 and 0.001). This is an issue for events with low probabilities. Having said that, why do you wish to use the Brier score for imbalanced data?

Comment: i wish to use it because i care about the the probabilty output of my model, should i use binary cross entropy then? it is important that i have well calibrated probabilites

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? Even, am in need of solution to this?

Comment: this doesn't seem to be solved